# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Query<DocumentData>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im trying to add a search function in our book store and fund a adaptable example in the internet, but unfortunately I get the following error:

Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Query<DocumentData'>'.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params.searchTerm)
        this.booksCollection = this.afs.collection('book-data', (ref) =>
          ref
            .where('buchstatus', '==', true)
            .filter((books) =>
              books.name.toLowerCase().includes(params.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            )
        );
      else
        this.booksCollection = this.afs.collection('book-data', (ref) =>
          ref.where('buchstatus', '==', true)
        );
    });
  }
```

I found some similar problems on stack overflow and imported the filter from rxjs/operators, but it is still not working.

Does anyone know what the problem could be, maybe its a silly fault but im trying to find a solution quite a long time and don't have an answer yet.

Comment: What library are you using for querying the data? What does the `.where` method return?

Comment: the .where method return the value true or false (boolean), which helps so that the offered book is visible in the market. Im using a firestore database and for quering the data, im using the library ActivatedRoute from angular/router

Answer (score 0):

1. The Angular FireStore Query API does not contain the `filter` option that you're attempting. You can find the available options [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#query-options).
2. You'd need to use the [`valueChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechanges-idfield-string-) method from AFS to get the changes.
3. The `filter` you're attempting is JS [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. It is **not** same as the RxJS [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) operator.
4. To switch from one observable to another you could use the RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator and use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) function to conditionally return an observable.

Try the following

```js
import { iif } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.pipe(
    switchMap((params: any) => 
      this.afs.collection(
        'book-data', 
        (ref) => ref.where('buchstatus', '==', true)
      ).valueChanges().pipe(
        switchMap((books: any) => 
          iif(
            () => !!params.searchTerm,
            of(
              books.filter((book: any) => 
                book.name.toLowerCase().includes(params.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              )
            ),
            of(books)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: (books) => {
      // handle response
    },
    error: (error) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruth, thanks a lot for response. It was understandable also for me as an Angular beginner :) It seems a problem, that the rxjs library is not compatible with Angular Ivy: But as this is a group project, my mate needs rxjs for any reason and I dont want to change his whole work... So if you know a different method (which works with Angular & AFS) to add a search function into our project, then im thankful for any hint, link or video :)

Comment: '''Error: node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:13:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (rxjs) which declares Observable has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.'''